KVM with openvswitch bridge guestos no internet
Running rockylinux9 with KVM and libvirt / virsh and I have installed openvswitch to be used as the bridge for the guestos's.
No matter what I have tried I cannot seem to get the virtual guest os's to obtain internet when connected to the openvswitch bridge. If I log into to cockpit dashboard the networks are show but the guest os VM will show IP address as unavailable.
Steps taken to configure the bridge and virtual network:

created openvswitch bridge (ovs-vsctl add-br bridge1)
added physical ethernet interface id to bridge (ovs-vsctl add-port bridge1 enp00)
I assigned an ip to the bridge but didn't seem a change the outcome so I skipped this the second time I configured the bridge.
created virtual network (virt-br1) to be used with the openvswitch bridge (virsh net-edit virt-br1, xml below)
created virtual machine (guest os - ubuntu)  with virt-install using virtual-network virt-br1

The guest os install will hang on networking configuration then ask to proceed without a internet connection.
I have two physical network adapters and both are able to ping to the public and private internet, I can SSH into both ip's to the host OS.
ovs-bridge config (ovs-vs show)
    Bridge bridge1
        Port bridge1
            Interface bridge1
                type: internal
        Port en00
            Interface en00
    ovs_version: "2.16.7"

command ip a shows the bridge link as unknown
bridge1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 

One thing that is interesting that I cannot seem to change even when using ip link nomaster command is that the interface that is configured to use the bridge shows ovs-system as the master not bridge1
enp00: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000

virtual network XML (virsh net-dumpxml)
<network connections='1'>
  <name>virt-br1</name>
  <uuid>8ff14db2-16e8-428c-a20a-ad04218271b</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='bridge1'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'/>
</network>

I have checked selinux logs (nothing denied) there are no firewalld rules that are blocking any connections and route tables have correct DNS and ips.
What is something I doing incorrect, or missing. Maybe additional troubleshooting suggestions?
